# Notation for a continious function represented as a list of numbers in discrete steps

Tags: notation

If we have some function, let's say
$$f(t) = \cos{(\omega_{0} t)} \text{,}$$
but I want to represent it for discrete steps of $t$, i.e. $\Delta t$. Is there a notation for this? I want to say a list of numbers from $f(t)$ in steps of $\Delta t$. Or that using $f(t)$ I generate a list of numbers for every $\Delta t$.

Perhaps
$$ f(\Delta t) = \{ \cos{(\omega_{0} \Delta t)} \}$$
?

Comment: The convention in digital signal processing is something like $f[n] = \cos(\omega_0 nT_s)$, where $T_s$ is the sampling period.  The square brackets indicate a discrete sequence vs. a continuous function.

Comment: @AndyWalls This looks like what I am after, however it doesn't seem to really show interval between data points by $\Delta t$. Is this just implicitly defined by $n$? So $n = T_s / \Delta t$?

Comment: $T_s$ is synonymous with $\Delta t$, they're the same thing.  $n$ is the sample index.  Maybe I'm not quite understanding what you want to show with notation.

Comment: If $T_s$ is how long the sample for then you will acquire $n$ samples in time $T_{s}$ then $T_{s} / n$ will give the time in-between two consecutive points, $\Delta t$. As I read your proposed notation (which i believe is close to what I want) there is no way of telling how many samples or the spacing in-between them.

Comment: $T_s$ is the standard notation for the time in between each sample point (which I believe is what you intend as the meaning of $\Delta t$).  If you need to limit the number of points, you can either call out a specific range of values for $n$, e.g. $n \in \{0, 1, \dots, N-1\}$, or you can multiply the continuous time function by a shifted and time-scaled rectangle function to bracket the interval of interest, or you can use unit step sequences to bracket the samples, i.e. $f[n] = \cos(\omega_0 n T_s) (u[n] - u[n-N])$

Comment: I think that's what I'll do, I'll simply define $n$ as you suggest. Thanks! If you want to get some credit, summarise what we have discussed as an answer and I will accept.